# How do I remove this [I] from my fish terminal?

Tags: terminal, fedora, konsole

This is what my terminal looks like

[image]

What is this and how do I get rid of it? I'm using Konsole on Fedora 31.

Comment: ...might be something in your prompt... which shell do you use? bash, csh, tcsh, ...? (`ps` will tell you.)

Comment: Fish as pointed out in the title

Answer (score 1):

That's the prompt. Define it with `fish_prompt`, take a look at https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#prompt.

> Unlike other shells, there is no prompt variable like PS1. To display your prompt, fish executes a function with the name fish_prompt, and its output is used as the prompt.
> You can define your own prompt:
>
> ```
> > function fish_prompt
>     echo "New Prompt % "
> end
> New Prompt %
> ```
>
> Multiple lines are OK. Colors can be set via set_color, passing it named ANSI colors, or hex
> RGB values:
>
> ```
> > function fish_prompt
>       set_color purple
>       date "+%m/%d/%y"
>       set_color FF0
>       echo (pwd) '>' (set_color normal)
>   end
> ```
>
> will look like
>
> ```
> 02/06/13
> /home/tutorial >
> ```
>
> You can choose among some sample prompts by
> running fish_config prompt. fish also supports RPROMPT through
> fish_right_prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer is that you've somehow set VIM keybindings on your Fish Terminal (it's showing the terminal is in 'insert' mode. You can undo this by running `set -e fish_key_bindings`.